# How can I add my post code NUT IDs to my Eurostar code?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a map with tmap based on the postal codes of my data. Now I have the problem that I don't know how to insert the postal codes in my eurostat code.

This is the code I have already written:

```
eurostat::get_eurostat_geospatial(nuts_level = 3) %>%
  filter(CNTR_CODE == "DE")
```

And i have already downloaded the file with the postcode, but i don't know how to paste it in there

Comment: Not really sure what you plan to do. You use a shape file containing the third level of the German NUTS code which corresponds to districts and a district mostly contains several different postal codes. So what's the idea behind doing this?

Comment: I have a table where wind turbine locations are represented by postal code. But I can't manage to map the table on a map. I thought that I have to insert the postal code inside the code to make the mapping work.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data (e.g. at least a few postalcodes). If your data is restricted maybe you could generate some sample data based on the postalcodes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the **eurostat** package does not give you access to geo data at the postal code level. But you can use the package **giscoR** instead. Essentially, it gives you access to the following zipped [shape file](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/postal-codes) on the Eurostat web site. Postal codes are represented as points.

```
library(giscoR)
postal_codes <- giscoR::gisco_get_postalcodes(country = "DEU")
```

Then, you can join the postal codes to your data set and visualize using `tmap`. If you need representation as region polygons, you can take the mapping from postal codes to NUTS3 regions from the potal code geo data set. In addition, you can get the NUTS3 region shapes either from the eurostat or the giscoR package.

```
giscoR::gisco_get_nuts(year = "2021", country = "DEU", nuts_level = 3)
```